# In Civ 5 can you destroy missiles and planes based in cities?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization 5 If I bomb an enemy city do missiles and planes based in that city take damage? Is there a way to tell which buildings are damaged or destroyed in an enemy city after bombing? Perhaps with a spy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attack a city e.g. by using bomb-attacks you are only damaging the health points of the city. You can't damage units in the city, neither ground units nor aircraft or missiles. Furthermore buildings are not damaged by the attacks.

To damage warplanes you could place Anti-Air units to intercept them or you can use your own fighter jets to clear the air space. That's an ability of them.
The only way to destroy missiles positioned in a city is to capture it or destroy it via nuclear missiles, two are needed to destroy a city.